# MySQL WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause, implode

Is it possible to have a WHERE clause after imploding array? I need to insert only rows where priority >=1. Thanks.

```
$array = array(); 
foreach ($priority as $priority) 
$array[] = "('$id', '$studentname', '$title', '$academicdiscipline', '$priority')";

$query = "INSERT INTO flux_project_selection (id, studentname, title,
academicdiscipline, priority)  VALUES ". implode(',', $array);
```

Comment: i added `php` tag. I apologize if I am wrong

Comment: `$query = "INSERT INTO flux_project_selection (id,studentname,title,academicdiscipline,priority) VALUES ". implode(',', $array). "WHERE priority >=1"; ` doesn't work. Example please?

Comment: @DrewPierce - you're not wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you filter it out in the foreach loop

Comment: Just lookup the proper SQL syntax. Obviously its `VALUES (val1, val2)`....and no the () of your function don't count...put () in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert statements shouldn't have a `where` clause. Instead use PHP to filter what goes into the `$array` variable. Here's an example:

```
<?php

$array = array(); 
foreach ($priority as $priority) {
    if ($priority >=1) {
        $array[] = "('$id', '$studentname', '$title', '$academicdiscipline', '$priority')"; 
    }
}

$query = "INSERT INTO flux_project_selection (id, studentname, title,
academicdiscipline, priority)  VALUES ". implode(',', $array);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks @BakerStreet. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Awesome! How about marking this as the right answer?